# PowerDesigner addin for VS.NET 2008 causes problems

Tags: visual-studio-2008, powerdesigner

I've installed PowerDesigner 15.1 on my machine, and plan to use its AddIn for VS.NET. But it causes the solution file (SLN) to be modified everytime I build, run, debug, or close the solution. And the VS doesn't change ANYTHING in the SLN file. (A compare to the history results in the message saying that the files are identical)

This even happens on the solutions that do not contain any PowerDesigner models.

As we're using TFS source control, this is a real problem. Everyone using PD on the team has to deal with this issue, and the checkout affects all other team members.

Doesn anyone has any experience with this? I can't find anyone reporting such a thing on the net.

Answer (score 0):

You should really use the PowerDesigner Newsgroup... not much help outside there.

Answer (score -2):

Just remove the PowerDesigner Plug-in for Visual Studio and this problem will not happen again.